# decode/encode error django python

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8

I have a list of keywords
`keywords = [u'encendió', u'polémica']`

I am trying to load them to a django model:

```
class myKeywords(model.Model):
    keyword = models.charField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.keyword.encode('utf-8')
```

This is what i am trying:

```
for k in keywords:
    keyObj, created = myKeywords.objects.get_or_create(keyword=k.decode('utf-8'))
    print created, keyObj
```

However, I keep getting the `django.utils.encoding.DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte`.

I have tried:

1. adding/removing `u` from infront of the keyword
2. removing `decode('utf-8')` while creating the keyword object -- doing this successfully creates and saves the object if there is a `u` appended infront of the keyword
3. removing `encode('utf-8')` from the `__unicode__(self)` function. -- doing this successfully prints the keyword

So, the only configuration that is working is as follows:

1. keep `u` appended in-front of the keyword
2. dont do `decode('utf-8')` or `encode('utf-8')` anyplace else

But I am not sure if this is the right way of doing this. Ideally I should be reading a keyword and decoding it as `utf-8` and then be saving it to the db. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__unicode__` method should return a unicode string, not a byte string. Therefore you should remove the `encode()` from your `__unicode__` method.

If your keywords have the `u''` prefix, then they are unicode strings as well, and don't have to be decoded either.

Comment: I want to be able to remove the `u` from before the keyword and have the program being able to decode it. How do I do that?

Comment: I am sorry, I am actually using `encode` in the __unicode__ method. So, should I remove `encode` as well ?

Comment: If you want to remove the `u` to make your code cleaner,  then you might want to use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. Otherwise, removing the `u` isn't a good idea. Unicode bugs occur when converting between unicode and byte strings. If you only deal with unicode strings, then you avoid those problems.

Comment: Yes, `encode` is why you're getting that specific error. `__unicode__` should (unsurprisingly) return a Unicode object, not encoded bytes.

Comment: Yes, you should remove the `encode()` from the unicode method, for the reason that Peter gives.

Comment: In general, you should expect to handle the decoding from bytes to Unicode when taking data from an external source, like a file (best handled with `codecs.open` on Python 2, Python 3 has better tools) or a web request. Django handles it for you when processing the web request, though, so it's rare that you need to do this at all in Django.

Comment: Its working. And I think I understand the rationale as well. Let me re-iterate: Adding a `u` makes the string unicode. Now that the string is already unicode doing either `encode` or `decode` will throw error.

Comment: The error specifically comes from mixing encoded bytestrings with Unicode. `encode` on a Unicode object is perfectly valid depending on what you want, but here it was causing your `__unicode__` method to return an object of the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `encode()` the strings to `utf-8` in `__unicode__()` method as Django returns all the strings from the database as `unicode`.

From docs,

> Because all strings are returned from the database as Unicode strings,
>   model fields that are character based (CharField, TextField, URLField,
>   etc) will contain Unicode values when Django retrieves data from the
>   database. This is always the case, even if the data could fit into an
>   ASCII bytestring.

Since your keywords are already `unicode` strings(as prefixed by `'u'`), you don't need to do `decode()` while printing. Remove the `decode()` also.

Your code should look like:

**models.py**

```
class myKeywords(model.Model):
    keyword = models.charField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s'%(self.keyword)


keywords = [u'encendió', u'polémica']
for k in keywords:
    keyObj, created = myKeywords.objects.get_or_create(keyword=k)
    print created, keyObj
```